# How to pull WordPress thumbnail images from source image URL

Tags: php, wordpress

one of our websites was built using Custom Fields in WordPress. Recently Custom Fields required an upgrade on the database, and before upgrading the database all the custom fields looked really messed up. After the upgrade it all worked fine, except for a gallery slider in the homepage:
https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/1C402P1V2N040K223L0b/Image%202018-09-24%20at%2011.02.47%20AM.png?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=2866569

Looking at the code, the images are trying to be pulled from a source that doesn't exist: 
https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/0S1J3b3r0o3R3l1X3n0A/Image%202018-09-24%20at%2011.05.28%20AM.png?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=2866569

However, the images in the custom fields are added correctly, so it should be pulling the correct source.

The php code in the index.php that is trying to make this happen is the following:

```
<img class="thumbnail" src="<?php echo $thumbnail_image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $thumbnail_image['alt']; ?>">
```

I am wondering if this is still the correct code we need to use since the database upgrade?

Here is the full code of the section that is displaying the slider in question:

```
<div class="gallery-wrapper"> 
  <img class="left-arrow svg" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/noun_53563_cc.svg">
  <div class="left-opacity"></div>
  <div class="center-gap"></div>
  <div class="right-opacity"></div>
  <img class="right-arrow svg" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/noun_53562_cc.svg">

  <div class="gallery">
    <?php while(have_rows("images", $about_section)): the_row(); ?>
      <?php
        $thumbnail_image = get_sub_field("thumbnail_image", $row);
        $enlarged_image = get_sub_field("enlarged_image", $row);
      ?>

      <div class="image-wrapper <?php echo $class; ?>">
        <div class="thumbnail-wrapper" data-anchor-target="#about" data-500-top-bottom="opacity: 1;" data-200-top-bottom="opacity: 0;">
          <div class="outer-border"></div>
          <div class="inner-border"></div>
         <img class="thumbnail" src="<?php echo $thumbnail_image['url']; ?> " alt="<?php echo $thumbnail_image['alt']; ?>">
        </div>

        <div class="lightbox-wrapper">
          <div class="lightbox-background"></div>

          <div class="enlarged-wrapper">
            <div class="close">Close</div>
            <img class="left-arrow svg" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/noun_53563_cc.svg">
            <img class="right-arrow svg" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/noun_53562_cc.svg">
            <img class="enlarged" src="<?php echo $thumbnail_image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $enlarged_image['alt']; ?>">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Custom Field is using Repeater and is Returning a Value of Image Array:
https://www.screencast.com/t/D1PmtVbl

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Show us more code. We need to know what `$thumbnail_image` is, at least.

Comment: I would assume you are using [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) and that field is setup to return an ID not a url. Double check your ACF config. Otherwise show us more clue. Do a var_dump on $thumbnail_image.

Comment: If you updated the ACF plugin, you should updated the dabase also by clicking inside the plugin. ACF will ask you to update the database.

Comment: @Michael I just edited my question with the full code on that specific section. Does this help?

Comment: @Ian I just edited my question with the full code on that specific section. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ACF (Advanced Custom Fields)?  If so I also did the upgrade in about 10 sites and didn't get any error.  I have both WP and ACF upgraded to the latest version.  First make sure your WP is also updated.

As for the code itself... I use `<?php the_field('image'); ?>` to get it printed.  You syntax looks a little different.  It will also depend on the format you configured the image output to be.  There are three options:  Image object, Image URL or Image ID.  I usually use Image URL, sometimes Image Object.  So your output will also depend on what you are getting from the `<?php the_field('image'); ?>` or `<?php get_field('image'); ?>` functions.

From your screenshots it look like you are getting image ID but you are expecting image URL.

Comment: Hi there, I just edited my question with the full code and the Return Value I am using in custom fields, Does this help?

Comment: I would debug to make sure I'm receiving the type of data I'm expecting and its structure.  Insert this right below $thumbnail_image and include in your question:  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($thumbnail_image); echo "</pre>";

Comment: From the code, I actually think he expects an image object.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check your ACF-JSON folder (path/to/wp-content/themes/your-theme/acf-json) if it exists and if so make it as writable. And verify if you have the correct field settings

```
{
        "key": "field_5ba25a93c0392",
        "label": "Thumbnail Image",
        "name": "thumbnail_image",
        "type": "image",
        "instructions": "",
        "required": 0,
        "conditional_logic": 0,
        "wrapper": {
            "width": "",
            "class": "",
            "id": ""
        },
        "return_format": "url", // Ruturn format should be URL not an ID
        "preview_size": "thumbnail",
        "library": "all",
        "min_width": "",
        "min_height": "",
        "min_size": "",
        "max_width": "",
        "max_height": "",
        "max_size": "",
        "mime_types": ""
    }
```

Alternatively you can do an if-else check:

```
<?php
function returnFormatUrl( $var )
{
    if ( wp_http_validate_url( $var ) )
        return $var;
    elseif ( is_int( $var ) )
        return wp_get_attachment_image_src( $var )[0];
    elseif ( is_array( $var ) )
        return $var['url'];
}

$thumbnail_image = returnFormatUrl( get_sub_field("thumbnail_image", $row) );
$enlarged_image = returnFormatUrl( get_sub_field("enlarged_image", $row) );
```